# Usage of java's scanner to read input

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

Suppose I have the following input:

```
3
24 1
4358 754
305 794
```

When I try to read it as follows it doesn't work:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while(sc.hasNextLine())
{
sc.nextLine();
int a = sc.nextInt();
int b = sc.nextInt(); 
//DoSomethingWithAandB
}
```

I do it that way because first I want to skip the first line. Then I read the two integers. After that if there is another line I go to it with sc.nextLine() and I read the integers again. What is wrong?

Comment: Let's check my logic. While there are lines do the following ==> 1) Place the cursor on the next line 2) Read the int and place the cursor just after it. 3) Same as 2.

Comment: And what is the output you're receiving? Have you printed out a and b within the loop to see what you're getting? Using println's in this way is called using the "poor-man's debugger" since it is lower tech than your typical IDE's debugger, but it can be quite effective and instructive

Comment: Myself, I would read in the first line and discard it, and then create a while loop and *within* the while loop read in each line into a String. I'd then create a separate Scanner within the loop based on that String and parse the ints using the 2nd line Scanner. I'd close the line Scanner at the end of the loop, and would only close the System.in based Scanner at the end of the program.

Comment: Question -- when does this code stop taking in input?  When is the loop supposed to end?  What "sentinel" value are you planning to use?

Comment: I am using this on SPOJ.com, so I can't see any output, I do not know where it stops. Otherwise I would indeed use the poor-man's debugger. The loop is supposed to end where there are no lines left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3 on the first line indicates how many lines you need to read, so you should use that information rather than only relying on **[hasNextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine--)**, which is not using all the information provided to you:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class FileInputExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("input.txt");
    try {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
      int n = scanner.nextInt(); // This reads the 3 in your example
      for (int line = 1; line <= n; line++) {
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        int b = scanner.nextInt();
        // Do something with a and b like store them in ArrayLists or something
        System.out.println(String.format("A: %d, B: %d", a, b));
      }
      scanner.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
A: 24, B: 1
A: 4358, B: 754
A: 305, B: 794
```

**input.txt:**

```
3
24 1
4358 754
305 794
```

---

If you do want to use **[hasNextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine--)** in a while loop, you need to skip the first line with the 3, outside the while loop:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class FileInputExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("input.txt");
    try {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
      scanner.nextLine(); // skip the 3 on the first line
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        int b = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(String.format("A: %d, B: %d", a, b));
      }
      scanner.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One question: How do we go to the next line in your code with hasNextLine()? If I am not wrong the only difference between my code and yours is that I had an extra "scanner.nextLine()" inside my loop. Does hasNextLine() put the cursor on that next line if it exists?

Comment: The only difference is you were not dealing with the line with the 3 line outside the while loop, see here for info on how `hasNextLine()` works: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine--

Answer (score 3):

In the input above, the first line is supposed to be the number of lines, so once you read it, you can do a loop then read the line and split it so you get your numbers.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int numberOfLines = in.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; ++i) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    String[] lineSplit = line.split(" ");
    int a = Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[0]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[1]);
    //DoSomethingWithAandB
}
```

If you don't need to read the first line, you can use while with `in.hasNextLine()`

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
in.nextInt();

while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    String[] lineSplit = line.split(" ");
    int a = Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[0]);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[1]);
    //DoSomethingWithAandB
}
```